# Running systemd-run --user inside a systemd service

Tags: systemd, systemd-service, dbus

I have a web app that handles user input, and as part of that, runs some commands with `systemd-run --user --scope ...` to limit memory and CPU usage.

The application runs fine when run normally, but when run as a systemd service, I get:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No medium found
```

What do I need to do in the unit for the service to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--user` contacts the per-user instance of systemd for that UID, which is only started when there is an actual *login session* for that UID. When there aren't any, you need to `loginctl enable-linger <user>` to have the service manager be always running for that user.

The webapp needs to have the correct `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=` in its environment so that it could find the bus socket; it's always at the same location `/run/user/<uid>`. (The directory will be created by systemd when linger is enabled.)

You will probably need to use `--service` instead of `--scope`. The latter won't be able to migrate your process between cgroups due to lack of "common ancestor" permissions, so it becomes necessary to have systemd itself start the process.

(In a user session, your own per-UID `user-1234.slice` cgroup is the common ancestor of both your interactive terminal cgroup and the new systemd scope cgroup, but when trying to do this from a service, the only common ancestor would be `-.slice` which you do not have permissions to.)

---

Configuring the webapp .service with a `PAMName=` so that the webapp actually runs in a login session would avoid some of the above problems, but I also have the feeling it'll cause new problems, so I'm not suggesting it as the first option.

Comment: I've been trying to test this with nested systemd-run. E.g. `sudo systemd-run --service simple -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001 systemd-run -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001 --user somecmd`. But I still get "Failed to connect to bus: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Your UID needs to match before you can connect to the user bus. Running a system service (why?) gives you an UID of 0. (Hopefully the webapp isn't running as UID 0?)

Comment: Ah yes, I was missing a `-p User=me`. Why doesn't `--scope` work though? I'd like to easily capture stdout/stderr...

Comment: You can get stdout/stderr with `--pipe`. Scopes won't work because you spawn the process in one cgroup (the service) and move it to another (the new scope), which is only permitted if you have the write permission to the source cgroup, the target cgroup, **and** their common ancestor cgroup – without that, it would be relatively easy to bypass the cgroup resource limits. So if you look at the cgroup tree with `systemd-cgls`, you'll see that the only common ancestor between `/system/foobar.service` and `/user/user-1001/somecmd.slice` is the root cgroup `/` (aka `-.slice`).